# Is View.setTag() a good place to save an Integer in onSaveInstanceState rather than SharedPreferences in onPause()?

Tags: android

Is `View.setTag(myInteger)` an easier and reasonably good place to save a member variable Integer in `onSaveInstanceState()` rather than saving it into a `SharedPreferences` in `onPause()`?

How about in onPause/onResume. Is it safe to store the integer using view.setTag()?

(Not to be lazy, but it seems like more trouble for the application to save state by using a SharedPreferences in onPause)

Answer (score 1):

No.  Not at all.  The View that you save it in is going to be destroyed by the time the Activity is created.  You need to save the integer in the provided Bundle.  It will be in the Bundle supplied in the `onCreate()` method when the Activity is recreated.  Alternatively, you can retrieve it in the Bundle on `onRestoredInstanceState()`.

Comment: How about in `onPause/onResume`. Is it safe to store the integer using `view.setTag()`?

Comment: No, for the same reason.  Views are to always be treated as volatile.  You can only save things in the TAG if it's guaranteed to exist when Views exist like list items in a ListView.  Even then, it's temporary and shouldn't be assumed to be there.